# Can a breakpoint display the contents of "const unsigned char* variable"?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints, lldb

I'm on the trail of why the contents of a TXT record in a Bonjour service discovery is sometimes being incompletely interpreted, and I've reached a point where it would be *really* useful to have a breakpoint print out the contents of an unsigned char in a callback (I've tried NSLog, but using NSLog in a threaded callback can get really tricky).

The callback function is defined this way:

```
static void resolveCallback(DNSServiceRef sdRef, DNSServiceFlags flags, uint32_t interfaceIndex, DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
                        const char* fullname, const char* hosttarget, uint16_t port, uint16_t txtLen,
                        const unsigned char* txtRecord, void* context) {
```

So I'm interested in the txtRecord

Right now my breakpoint is using:

```
 memory read --size 4 --format x --count 4 `txtRecord`
```

But that's only because that was an example on the lldv.llvm.org example page ;-)  It's certainly showing data that I expect to be there, partially.

Do I have to apply informed knowledge of the length or can the breakpoint be coded such that it uses the length that is present?  I'm thinking that instead of "hard coding" the two 4s in the example there ought to be a way to wrap in other read instructions inside back ticks like I did with the variable name.

Looking at http://lldb.llvm.org/varFormats.html I thought I'd try a format of C instead of x but that prints out series of dots which must mean I picked a wrong format or something.

I just tried

```
memory read `txtRecord`
```

and that's almost exactly what I wanted to see as it gives:

```
0x1c5dd884: 10 65 6e 30 3d 31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e 31 2e 33  .en0=192.168.1.3
0x1c5dd894: 36 0a 70 6f 72 74 3d 35 30 32 37 38 00 00 00 00  6.port=50278....
```

This looks really close:

```
memory read `txtRecord` --format C
```

giving:

```
0x1d0c6974: .en0=192.168.1.36.port=50278....
```

If that's the best I can get, I guess I can deal with the length bytes in front of each of the two strings in that txtRecord.

I'm asking this question because I'd like to display the actual and correct values... the bug is that sometimes the IP address comes back wrong, losing the frontmost 1, other times the port comes back "short" (in network byte order) with non-numeric characters at the end, like "502¿" instead of "50278" (in this example run).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial response to this question, while informative, was not complete.  I originally thought the problem being reported was just about printing a c-string array of type `unsigned char *` where the default formatters (`char *`) weren't being used.  That answer comes first.  Then comes the answer about how to print this (somewhat unique) array of pascal strings data that the program is actually dealing with.

**First answer:** lldb knows how to handle the `char *` well; it's the `unsigned char *` bit that is making it behave a little worse than usual.  e.g. if `txtRecord` were a `const char *`,

```
(lldb) p txtRecord
(const char *) $0 = 0x0000000100000f51 ".en0=192.168.1.36.port=50278"
```

You can copy the type summary lldb has built in for `char *` for `unsigned char *`.  `type summary list` lists all of the built in type summaries; copying lldb-179.5's summaries for `char *`:

```
(lldb) type summary add -p -C false -s ${var%s} 'unsigned char *'
(lldb) type summary add -p -C false -s ${var%s} 'const unsigned char *'

(lldb) fr va txtRecord
(const unsigned char *) txtRecord = 0x0000000100000f51 ".en0=192.168.1.36.port=50278"
(lldb) p txtRecord
(const unsigned char *) $2 = 0x0000000100000f51 ".en0=192.168.1.36.port=50278"
(lldb)
```

Of course you can put these in your `~/.lldbinit` file and they'll be picked up by Xcode et al from now on.

**Second answer**: To print the array of pascal strings that this is actually using, you'll need to create a python function.  It will take two arguments, the size of the pascal string buffer (`txtLen`) and the address of the start of the buffer (`txtRecord`).  Create a python file like `pstrarray.py` (I like to put these in a directory I made, `~/lldb`) and load it into your lldb via the `~/.lldbinit` file so you have the command available:

```
command script import ~/lldb/pstrarray.py
```

The python script is a little long; I'm sure someone more familiar with python could express this more concisely.  There's also a bunch of error handling which adds bulk.  But the main idea is to take two parameters:  the size of the buffer and the pointer to the buffer.  The user will express these with variable names like `pstrarray txtLen txtRecord`, in which case you could look up the variables in the current frame, but they might also want to use an acutal expression like `pstrarray sizeof(str) str`.  So we need to pass these parameters through the expression evaluation engine to get them down to an integer size and a pointer address.  Then we read the memory out of the process and print the strings.

```
import lldb
import shlex
import optparse

def pstrarray(debugger, command, result, dict):
  command_args = shlex.split(command)
  parser = create_pstrarray_options()
  try:
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(command_args)
  except:
   return

  if debugger and debugger.GetSelectedTarget() and debugger.GetSelectedTarget().GetProcess():
    process = debugger.GetSelectedTarget().GetProcess()
    if len(args) < 2:
      print "Usage: pstrarray size-of-buffer pointer-to-array-of-pascal-strings"
      return
    if process.GetSelectedThread() and process.GetSelectedThread().GetSelectedFrame():
      frame = process.GetSelectedThread().GetSelectedFrame()

      size_of_buffer_sbval = frame.EvaluateExpression (args[0])
      if not size_of_buffer_sbval.IsValid() or size_of_buffer_sbval.GetValueAsUnsigned (lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS) == lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS:
        print 'Could not evaluate "%s" down to an integral value' % args[0]
        return
      size_of_buffer = size_of_buffer_sbval.GetValueAsUnsigned ()

      address_of_buffer_sbval = frame.EvaluateExpression (args[1])
      if not address_of_buffer_sbval.IsValid():
        print 'could not evaluate "%s" down to a pointer value' % args[1]
        return
      address_of_buffer = address_of_buffer_sbval.GetValueAsUnsigned (lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS)
      # If the expression eval didn't give us an integer value, try it again with an & prepended.
      if address_of_buffer == lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS:
        address_of_buffer_sbval = frame.EvaluateExpression ('&%s' % args[1])
        if address_of_buffer_sbval.IsValid():
          address_of_buffer = address_of_buffer_sbval.GetValueAsUnsigned (lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS)
      if address_of_buffer == lldb.LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS:
        print 'could not evaluate "%s" down to a pointer value' % args[1]
        return

      err = lldb.SBError()
      pascal_string_buffer = process.ReadMemory (address_of_buffer, size_of_buffer, err)
      if (err.Fail()):
        print 'Failed to read memory at address 0x%x' % address_of_buffer
        return
      pascal_string_array = bytearray(pascal_string_buffer, 'ascii')
      index = 0
      while index < size_of_buffer:
        length = ord(pascal_string_buffer[index])
        print "%s" % pascal_string_array[index+1:index+1+length]
        index = index + length + 1

def create_pstrarray_options():
  usage = "usage: %prog"
  description='''print an buffer which has an array of pascal strings in it'''
  parser = optparse.OptionParser(description=description, prog='pstrarray',usage=usage)
  return parser

def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
  parser = create_pstrarray_options()
  pstrarray.__doc__ = parser.format_help()
  debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f %s.pstrarray pstrarray' % __name__)
```

and an example program to run this on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
    unsigned char str[] = {16,'e','n','0','=','1','9','2','.','1','6','8','.','1','.','3','6',
                           10,'p','o','r','t','=','5','1','6','8','7'};
    uint8_t *p = str;
    while (p < str + sizeof (str))
    {
        int len = *p++;
        char buf[len + 1];
        strlcpy (buf, (char*) p, len + 1);
        puts (buf);
        p += len;
    }
    puts ("done"); // break here
}
```

and in use:

```
(lldb) br s -p break
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 231 at a.c:17, address = 0x0000000100000ed7
(lldb) r
Process 74549 launched: '/private/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
en0=192.168.1.36
port=51687
Process 74549 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0000000100000ed7 a.out`main + 231 at a.c:17, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    #0: 0x0000000100000ed7 a.out`main + 231 at a.c:17
   14           puts (buf);
   15           p += len;
   16       }
-> 17       puts ("done"); // break here
   18   }
(lldb) pstrarray sizeof(str) str
en0=192.168.1.36
port=51687
(lldb)
```

While it's cool that it's possible to do this in lldb, it's not as smooth as we'd like to see.  If the size of the buffer and the address of the buffer were contained in a single object, `struct PStringArray {uint16_t size; uint8_t *addr;}`, that would work much better.  You could define a type summary formatter for all variables of type `struct PStringArray` and no special commands would be required.  You'd still need to write a python function, but it could get all the information it needed out of the object directly so it would disappear into the lldb type format system.  You could just write `(lldb) p strs` and the custom formatter function would be called on `strs` to print all the strings in there.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  A whole lotta learning to be had in there.  That's what weekends are for, I guess.  Interestingly, I get a string with an apparent length byte in front (but it's only valid for the first part of the string): $2 = 0x20a6d8c4 "\x10en0=192.168.1.36\nport=51687"

Comment: @tobinjim: `txtRecord` is a sequence of so-called "Pascal Strings" (explained e.g. in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: @MartinR thank you.  From that documentation I see that the "\n" is being interpreted as an ASCII character (new line) when in fact it is the length value for the following string "port=51687"

Comment: @JasonMolenda That's the most informative answer I've come across in a long time, not just because it answers what I asked, but because you understood what I should have been asking, and the answer you provided shines light on all manner of capability within the debugger that I bet few venture into.  As much as I would prefer to always stay high level, knowing how to make a debugger sing can be a real boon to development efforts.  So a great many thanks to you for taking extra time on this.